# blanket trait implementation for generic trait

Tags: rust, traits

the [rust docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#:%7E:text=Implementations%20of%20a%20trait%20on%20any%20type%20that,on%20any%20type%20that%20implements%20the%20Display%20trait.) gives the following example for blanket implementations

```
impl<T: Display> ToString for T {
    // --snip--
}
```

My somewhat more complicated trait does not allow me to write a blanket implementation.

```
/// a fixed size 2D array (WxH) that can be indexed by [usize;2]
pub trait Grid<C: Copy + Eq, const W: usize, const H: usize>:
    IndexMut<[usize; 2], Output = Option<C>>
{
}

// allow to transform one grid implementation into another 
// as long as they contain the same elements and have the same size
impl<C, O, I, const W: usize, const H: usize> From<I> for O
where
    O: Default + Grid<C, W, H>,
    I: Grid<C, W, H>,
    C: Copy
{
    fn from(input: O) -> O {
        let mut output = O::default();
        for i in 0..O::W {
            for j in 0..O::H {
                output[[i, j]] = input[[i, j]];
            }
        }
        output
    }
}
```

The errors say

```
the type parameter `C` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates

the const parameter `W` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
expressions using a const parameter must map each value to a distinct output value
proving the result of expressions other than the parameter are unique is not supported
```

It feels like it is constrained via the `O: Grid<Player, W, H>` but that doesn't seem to be the right constraint.

Rhe errors around the const generic parameters are secondary (a red herring?). When I replace them with constants, the error around C (the element type) still remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your variables `C`, `W`, and `H` could have more than one value, as far as the compiler is concerned. Consider what happens if `I` implements `Grid<Foo, 1, 2>` *and also* `Grid<Foo, 500, 50>`: it is ambiguous which `Grid` implementation your blanket `From` implementation should be using. (`C` can't actually have multiple values for a given `O` or `I`, but the compiler doesn't actually reason that out.)

The solution to that problem is to change your trait's *generics* to *associated types* (and associated constants), which means that the trait cannot be implemented more than once for the same self type:

```rust
use std::ops::IndexMut;
/// a fixed size 2D array (WxH) that can be indexed by [usize;2]
pub trait Grid: IndexMut<[usize; 2], Output = Option<Self::Component>>
{
    type Component: Copy + Eq;
    const WIDTH: usize;
    const HEIGHT: usize;
}

// allow to transform one grid implementation into another 
// as long as they contain the same elements and have the same size
impl<O, I> From<I> for O
where
    O: Default + Grid,
    O::Component: Copy,
    I: Grid<Component = O::Component, WIDTH = O::WIDTH, HEIGHT = O::HEIGHT>,
{
    fn from(input: O) -> O {
        let mut output = O::default();
        for i in 0..O::W {
            for j in 0..O::H {
                output[[i, j]] = input[[i, j]];
            }
        }
        output
    }
}
```

However, this still will not compile, for several reasons:

- You can't write a `From` impl for any two types that meet some trait bounds, because it might overlap with *some other crate's* `From` impl for any two types that meet different bounds — and it always overlaps with the blanket `From<T> for T` in the standard library.

  In general, you can only implement `From<TypeYouDefined> for T` or `From<T> for TypeYouDefined` — not a fully generic, blanket `From` impl. You can define your own conversion trait, though.
- You can't actually write a bound that two traits' associated constants are equal, as my code suggests — the compiler assumes it must be a type constraint. I don't know if there's a solution to that problem.